# looking for a way to script a mac os install

Tags: macos, install, automation

I have 100+ laptops that I need to image to Catalina and want a way to script the install. I know this at the very least used to be possible because it worked for us in the past.

My goal is to option boot > enter firmware password > select boot drive. From there it would remove the firmware password, erase the drive then install the os. I just need it to get to the startup screen.

I poked around the hidden files of an already setup boot drive but i dont know where I would go from there. If there is a better place to ask this I would love to know that as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Off topic whey Cataliina now - it is likely to unsupported by the end of year when the new version comes out

Comment: Consider [Mac Deploy Stick](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/). Once your desired routine is set up and bounced to a thumb drive, you boot a Mac to its local Recovery, start the `run` script in terminal, and the rest is magic.